# how to handle a long URL with multiple $_GET?

Tags: php

i have a long url with multiple $_GET value, it looks like this :
index.php?Category=music&Id=3211&Delete=yes
and in the php file, i have a if condition like this :

```
if(isseet($_GET['Category']) && isset($_GET['Id']) && !isset($_GET['Delete'])){
echo 'Valid page';
}elseif(if(isseet($_GET['Category']) && isset($_GET['Id']) && isset($_GET['Delete'])){
echo 'delete !';
}
```

as you see, this is a very complicate if condition, when i have around 20 similar condition like this. and i want to know if we have some simple ways to do this, for example a SWITCH
thank you

Comment: It depends on what all the variables will mean and what you intend to use them for. A good answer to one situation is not a good answer in another. I suggest asking the actual question you have, instead of trying to make a generic version of it.

Comment: "Delete"? If you are going to be deleting things in response to this request, then it is almost certain that you should be using POST, not GET.

Answer (score 1):

```
// if switch is true, check if all are set; if it's
// false check for none to be set. Defaults to true
function array_all_set($keys, $vector, $switch=true)
{
    foreach($keys as $key)
        if($switch == !isset($vector[$key]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

And now use it like this:

```
if(array_all_set(array("Category", "Id"), $_GET)
   && array_all_set(array("Delete"), $_GET, false)) {/* stuff */}
```

I know it's not much of an improvement with just 3 values, but for 20 values like you said, it's all about adding values to that array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using code like this:

```
if(isseet($_GET['Category']) )
//do something...
```

That's wrong! you need to sanitize your input. But, I'll assume you already know that. Back to your problem, you should use a fairly more complex structure to handle your request variable, like for instance a dictionary, and then use it to validate your requests. An idea would be something like this:

```
class RequestDictionary
{
  private $dictionary; 

  public function RequestDictionary()
  {
    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value )
    {
      $this->dictionary[$key] => clean_var($value);
    }
  }

  public function hasKeys($keys = array())
  {
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
      if ( !isset( $this->dictionary[$key] ) )
        return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

And then, in your PHP pages you should make a method in your page to validate the requested Url, like this one:

```
function Validate()
{
  $requestDict = new RequestDictionary();
  return $requestDict->hasKeys(array('category', 'id', 'whatever'));
}
```

Your code should be very simplified. Remember that whenever you are coding many times the same snippet, something is not being abstracted. Sorry for the ultra-long answer, but I had to place most of the class so you may see it well,

Hope I can help!
David